# Laravel using paginate() with select() method

Tags: laravel, pagination

Is it possible to use paginate() with the select() method? Using the code below I get the error:

**Call to a member function paginate() on a non-object**

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM items';
$results = DB::select($query)->paginate(10);
```

I know the following code works with paginate() with just the table() method:

```
$results = DB::table('plans_shared')->paginate(10);
```

It seems much easier for me to use the select() since I have many conditional AND/WHERE clauses

Answer (score 1):

select() method returns array so paginate() cannot be called on it. You can only try to use `\Paginator::make(DB::select($query))` if you like

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array and want to paginate it use `Paginate::make()` [Paginate Laravel 4.2](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/pagination)

Ex:

```
$pages = Paginate::make(DB::select($query), 10);
```

Comment: What about Laravel 5?

Answer (score -1):

$items = DB::table('team')
->selectRaw('SELECT *,earth_distance(ll_to_earth(team.lat, team.lng), ll_to_earth(23.1215939329,113.3096030895)) AS distance')
->whereRaw('earth_box(ll_to_earth(23.1215939329,113.3096030895),1000) @> ll_to_earth(team.lat, team.lng)')
->paginate(10);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).